# Confusion in SQLite version

Tags: sqlite, version

If you look at the [Release History of SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html), you're presented with a list of releases:

- 2017-06-17 (3.18.2)
- 2017-06-16 (3.18.1) `<-- :o`
- 2017-06-08 (3.19.3)
- 2017-05-25 (3.19.2)
- ...

Why the releases after `2017-06-16 (3.19.3)` have a decreased sub version number of `18` instead of rationally sticking to the current subversion and incrementing the third number?! Does the *new* changes applied to the `3.18.2` are also present in the currently *"latest"* version?! Or, maybe I'm totally lost in a desert of ignorance?!! Please shed some lights on this :)

Comment: Interesting question to ask the SQLite support. However, the question seems off-topic or maybe off-site for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 3.18.1 is the same as version 3.18.0, but with a bug fixed.

This version was made for users who did not want to update to 3.19.x but still wanted the bugfix.

Comment: Thank you. So, the new changes applied to the `3.18.1` & `3.18.2` are also present in the currently _"latest"_ version (`3.19.3`), don't they?

Comment: Maybe the release history page has information about that …

Comment: You're right: _Of course the newer versions should contain the fixes for the known issues._ Thank you.